# Show PDF file from SQL Database

Tags: c#, pdf, binary

I already uploaded pdf files into my sql database as binary data file. I want to retrieve this file and open it with Adobe Reader on my form. But I couldn't solve it in C# code.

I want to retrieve the pdf file which id number = textbox1 and I want to load that file to `axAcroPDF1` Adobe viewer.

I want to write this code to form load action.

```
textBox1.text= clipboard.gettext();
```

then retrieve code.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to retrieve the data from the database in the same way as you would any other data.  That will give you a Byte array.  You can then call File.WriteAllBytes to write that data to a file.  You can use the Path.GetTempFileName method to create a temp file to write the data to if appropriate.  You can then use that path to open the file in your PDF reader as you normally would.